# Why "JMeter" response time is different than 'Microsft Visual Studio Web Performance and Load Test" response time?

Tags: jmeter, azure-devops, performance-testing, load-testing

'Microsft Visual Studio Web Performance and Load Test' and 'JMeter' response times are different. 'JMeter' is always showing higher response times.

I could not find specific reason regarding this problem, Is it fault of 'Microsft Visual Studio Web Performance and Load Test'  or 'JMeter'?

'Microsft Visual Studio Web Performance and Load Test'  response time is similar browser response time.

For instance, 'Jmeter' response time takes 0,7 sec while load to "google.com". On the other hand Browser Response time takes 0,3 sec and 'Microsft Visual Studio Web Performance and Load Test'  Response Time takes 0,4 sec.

[image]

[image]

When I used JMeter in Non-GUI mode, the result didn't change, it even increased.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly Remove Summary Report and [View Result Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

> View Results Tree MUST NOT BE USED during load test as it consumes a lot of resources (memory and CPU)

Google takes the same or less create Test Plan as follows:

1. Ctrl+0, Ctrl+1 (Create Thread Group and HTTP Request)
2. In HTTP Request Set Server Name or IP to `www.google.com` and uncheck `Use KeepAlive`
3. Ctrl +Shift + S - Save file as google.jmx
4. Execute non GUI in JMETER\bin folder

   ```
    jmeter -n -t google.jmx -f -l google.jtl
   ```
5. Check in google.jtl file: second column `elapsed` show be less than 300ms
   [image]

See also [JMeter's Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean)

> Use non-GUI mode: jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l test.jtl
>
> Use as few Listeners as possible; if using the -l flag as above they can all be deleted or disabled.
> Don't use "View Results Tree" or "View Results in Table" listeners during the load test, use them only during scripting phase to debug your scripts.

Comment: Unfortunately. I follow your steps but I could not see 300 ms. It still changes between 500 ms and 900 ms. It is also weird. Because it should be consistent, shouldn't it? Why it is varying all the time?

Comment: @Berker Start a new empty file and follow my steps

Comment: It's so strange. When I put my jmx file in another directory (like D:\) rather than (jmeter\bin), response time takes  between 500ms and 900ms. But if I put jmx file in jmeter/bin directory, response time takes 300 ms. You can check. Anyway, thank you so much. It worked!